# ffmpeg stream test pattern to VLC via TCP?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, vlc-media-player, streaming

I'm trying to find an incantation of `ffmpeg` that streams a test pattern I can see in VLC over TCP:

```
ffmpeg \
  -f lavfi \
  -i testsrc=size=800x600:rate=24 \
  -c:v libx264 \
  -tune zerolatency \
  -pix_fmt yuv420p \
  -profile:v baseline \
  -b:v 300K \
  -minrate 100K \
  -maxrate 1M \
  -bufsize 2M \
  -g 24 \
  -f h264 \
  tcp://127.0.0.1:1234?listen
```

And launch `vlc` with options:

```
vlc tcp://@127.0.0.1:1234
```

This appears to produce a black video which is not this expected pattern:

[image]

HOW CAN I SEND A TEST PATTERN FROM FFMPEG I CAN VISUALIZE IN VLC?

https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-all.html#Main-options

screenshot taken from: https://www.bogotobogo.com/FFMpeg/ffmpeg_video_test_patterns_src.php

Answer (score 0):

Change `-f h264` to `-f mpegts`, or whatever format you prefer that supports streaming.

See `ffmpeg -muxers` for a list of muxers.